# ambari hive export des not include all of data set

Tags: hadoop, hive, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

I'm using ambari and hive view. When i try to export a data set that is about 100,000 records to CSV, it sends an incomplete data set. It ends up only having about 30,000 records in the file.
Image:
[image]

Is there any config setting that can be changed?
Has anyone else experienced this problem?

I'm using Hortonworks HDP 2.5, with hive 1.2.1

Comment: What is Ambari version ? I am able to download all rows in Ambari 2.1.2

Comment: @ShubhangiPardeshi I'm using ambari 2.4